# Connect the virtual serial port of one DOSBox to another DOSBox

Tags: assembly, masm, x86-16, dosbox

How to create a simple-format text chat connect between two dosbox using virtual serial port communication.

Is it possible to do that?

I'm looking for some resources on my project.

Comment: That should be possible, because DOSBox probably exhibits the _Serial Port_ I/O ports that you can use. It remains the task to connect both DOSBox'es - which I know nothing about.

Comment: Of course it's possible to write programs that display on the screen and send/receive bytes on serial ports.  Asking how to get started writing such a program is not an on-topic SO question (too broad), so I retitled to ask about the part about configuring DOSBox.

Comment: @Peter Cordes  I’ve figured out the configuration in DOSbox, thanks ! actually my topic is to mention about how to create a simple text chat using assembly 8086. I’m not sure how to begin the coding part.... is there any suggestion or useful resources can be share ? Thanks

Comment: Requests for tutorials are off-topic for Stack Overflow.  See [ask].  That's *why* I edited your question so the on-topic part was emphasized, instead of just voting to close it as off-topic.  (As far as suggestions, well you can store to VGA memory directly, and read/write the UART directly at its I/O port address.  Or you can use BIOS or DOS calls for keyboard input and screen or file output, and also serial port I/O.  See http://www.ctyme.com/rbrown.htm.

Comment: @Peter Cordes Sorry for the request.  I’m new to the forum sir. I will learn how to ask on stackoverflow. Thanks for the suggestion!